# SwiftUI previews not working when using Firebase/Analytics pod

Tags: ios, swiftui, firebase-analytics, xcode12

Seems that after updating Xcode 12 to beta 5, SwiftUI previews are not working anymore when using Firebase/Analytics pod. Previews are failing with error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

----------------------------------------

SchemeBuildError: Failed to build the scheme "Boo"

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Link Boo (arm64):
ld: in /Users/../Boo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRAnalyticsConnector_e321ed8e3db06efc9803f6c008e67a34.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/.../Boo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following workaround (credit to user on Apple Developer forums) worked for me:

Add "arm64" to the excluded architectures for the debug scheme for any targets that have Firebase Analytics.

This will cause you problems if you need to debug to an actual iOS device, obviously. But you can remove it when you need to test on a device.

Comment: Having this same problem in 2022, is this *still* the only way around this?

Answer (score 16):

To exclude the arm64 architecture only when running on a simulator, add the "Any iOS Simulator SDK" qualifier in the build settings.  Then you won't have to remove this setting when testing on a physical device.

[image]

To add the qualifier, click on the little plus button, as shown.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! You don't have to deal with adding and removing the flag when switching from simulator to device 

Comment: Important to say, that you have to clean build and remove derived data after setting this parameter. Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: This is great advice and worked for me as well, especially the carful application only to iOS simulators... I wonder what happens to a dev on Apple Silicon Macs?

Answer (score 4):

## How to Add arm64 as an Excluded Architecture

The accepted answer also worked for me. But I didn't know how to do this as I have never done it before so I wanted to show you the steps I took to accomplish this.

[image: Build Settings]

1. Select your project in the Project Navigator
2. Select your project in the Project Settings
3. At the top, select "Build Settings"
4. Then select "All" to show all build settings
5. At the top, you will see a section called "**Architecture**". In this section is "**Excluded Architectures**". You want to expand this. And then next to **Debug**, double-click, and type in "arm64".

Answer (score 4):

Add this check at start of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and preview mod will ignoring external modules

```swift
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"] == "1" {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a super easy fix for previews in a project with tons of dependencies that were breaking previews all the time!

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This is the way to go. It's way less intrusive than changing build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 12, beta 6

The Valid Architectures build setting has been removed in Xcode 12. If you had values in this build setting, they're causing a problem and need to be removed.

I was able to "clear out" the VALID_ARCHS build setting by adding it back in as a User-Defined build setting (with no values), running the project (which failed), and then deleting the VALID_ARCHS build setting.

My Architectures build setting is Standard Architectures.